# D3.js multiple line graph transitions

Tags: graph, d3.js, line, transition

I am wondering why the transitions on this multiple line graph are jumpy compared to the animated single line graph it is based on: http://www.animatedcreations.net/d3/lineChartAnimated.html

Fiddle provided here:
http://jsfiddle.net/user2477109/QBDGB/

Is the problem updating all of the paths separately?  It does seem inefficient.  Thanks.

```
graph.select(".line1").attr("d", line).attr("transform", null);
graph.select(".line2").attr("d", line).attr("transform", null);
graph.select(".line3").attr("d", line).attr("transform", null);
graph.select(".line4").attr("d", line).attr("transform", null);

// slide the line left
path1
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(t-n+1) + ")");

path2
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(t-n+1) + ")");

path3
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(t-n+1) + ")");

path4
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(t-n+1) + ")");

// slide the x-axis left
    axis.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease("linear")
    .call(xAxis)
    .each("end", tick);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `.ease('linear')` option:

```
path1
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease("linear")
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/QBDGB/4/

As a remark you should consider looping on the four lines or using another iterator for the lines as here you hard code the number of lines

Comment: I can't believe I missed that!  Also, I was wondering why the single line has the constant smooth redraw on the line, but the four line graph does not?  Is it possible to achieve that effect with more than one line?

Comment: Just use it on every transition, as you can see in the jsFiddle.